# Split string in 3 values for variable

Tags: php, split

I have this String:

```
$folders="Folder1_w_r-Folder2_!w_r-Folder3_!w_!r";
```

I would like to export a variable,  formatted in the following method:

```
$Folder1=w_r; $Folder2=!w_r; $Folder3=!w_!r;
```

I used the `explode ()` function. but I was not able to assign the right values ​​to variables.
Keep in mind that the folders do not have the same length could be called: Pictures, Videos, Documents etc. .. 
So you can not use `str_split ()` or `chunk_split ()`

Thanks to all

Comment: Is your separator always the `-` character?

Comment: If the variable names are assigned dynamically, how are you planning to access them once they're assigned? Wouldn't you be better off outputting an array? (eg. `$folders = array('Folder1' => 'w_r', 'Folder2' => '!w_r')` etc.)

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, because the string is read from the database.if it can work, what should I do?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? What are you doing with the data once it has been assigned?

Comment: Folder1_w_r-Folder2_!w_r-Folder3_!w_!r <-This is a reading from database and i want to save in a variable with the same name, BUT i don't know this names... the solution probably is with the eval () function

Comment: daaamn.. hehehe.. nope!! look at my last reply to Veda..probably it was me I explained myself badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_match_all to get the 2 parts and then $$var to assign each part to its correct var:

```
$folders="Folder1_w_r-Folder2_!w_r-Folder3_!w_!r";
//the Folder1 part can contain any character except _ or -
//that is followed by an _
//the w_r can contain anything except the - character
//something like /([A-Za-z0-9]+)_([a-z!]+)/ should also work in your example (not tested) 
preg_match_all('/([^_-]+)_([^-]+)/',$folders,$matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $key=>$val)
    $$matches[1][$key] = $matches[2][$key];
echo $Folder1.' '.$Folder2; // output: w_r !w_r
```

Your explode trick will probably also work...

Keep in mind that if $folders is from _GET or _POST (or from anywhere else that is user given content) that this is a huge security risk.

Comment: I do not know if I'm doing something wrong .. but does not work

Comment: ok i understand how it works ... but the variables should automatically generate.. then the name of the folder must be generated by the value of the string

Comment: @napster3world I don't understand then what you want exactly. Also read billyonecan his comment on your post. Array's are usually (always) better for this kind of tasks (although you can get it to work this way...).

Comment: because the field is not always the same. can sometimes be (images, video, audio), other times it can be (sounds, img, videos). So if I have to assign the same variables I do not know the real name they have. Put them in an array would solve the problem, but must be formatted exactly like $ folders = array ('name' => value, 'name 2' => value) and do not know the exact names. if I save the database in the array output becomes a string.

Comment: Your function would work if: $Folder1 and $Folder2 would take their name from, each first value .. understand? XD.. with the eval() function is possible?

Comment: @napster3world don't do eval. My $$ is already evil, eval is even worse.

Comment: i have solved with a join in SQL for the selection of the name. in this case for output echo $$row['name']; thank you... you have solved my huge doubts